# See Inside R function from package

Tags: r

Is there a way to see what happens inside the function from the library or a package in R? I want to get an in-depth look at what happens inside the code. the function that I want to see is trimcluster [http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucakche/](http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucakche/)

Comment: You'd probably be best off searching the package name on github and viewing the source.

Comment: thank you very much, i dont know about that before

Comment: If your IDE has a debugger you can use `debugonce(trimcluster)` and then click through each step of the function and also jump into other functions that are being called.